# Qt qml how to check only one switch from a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a qml ListView that show languages and respective switches as shown in the code below. The English language is initially selected. Howerver, with this code I can select multiple languages. I want to select only one (when I select one language the others are automatically unselected). How to do it?

```
 ListView{
    id: langlist
    clip: true

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { selected:true; title: "English"}
        ListElement { selected:false;title: "French"}
        ListElement { selected:false;title: "German"}
        ListElement { selected:false;title: "Italian"}
    }

    delegate: Rectangle{
        id: langelement
        height: 70
        width: parent.width
        color: "transparent"
        Label{
            anchors.left: langelement.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 30
            anchors.top : langelement.top
            anchors.topMargin: 30
            text: model.title
            font.family: "Lato"
            font.pixelSize: 30
            font.bold: false
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        }

        Switch {
            id: control
            anchors.right: langelement.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 30
            anchors.top : langelement.top
            anchors.topMargin: 20
            checked: model.selected
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should use a ComboBox for that, since that serves the purpose of selecting a single item.

If you persist on having a ListView you can do it as such:

```
ListView{
    id: langlist
    clip: true

    property int selectedIndex : 0

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { selected:true; title: "English"}
        ListElement { selected:false;title: "French"}
        ListElement { selected:false;title: "German"}
        ListElement { selected:false;title: "Italian"}
    }

    delegate: Rectangle{
        id: langelement
        height: 70
        width: parent.width
        color: "transparent"
        Label{
            anchors.left: langelement.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 30
            anchors.top : langelement.top
            anchors.topMargin: 30
            text: model.title
            font.family: "Lato"
            font.pixelSize: 30
            font.bold: false
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        }

        Switch {
            id: control
            anchors.right: langelement.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 30
            anchors.top : langelement.top
            anchors.topMargin: 20
            checked: selectedIndex == index

            onToggled: selectedIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says "Invalid property name "onToggled"".
I'm using Qt 5.8.0 and QtQuick.Controls 2.0
I'm creating an application following a design model. The model doesn't use a combobox but language name with a switch. So that's why I chose ListView.

Comment: I've changed onToggled by onPressed. It still doesn't work. When I check the switch it turns on and directly turns off, dispite the selectedIndex property get the new value of the index.